# complex HTML page sluggish

Tags: html, performance

For network intern purposes I have a quite complex html page, consisting of about 5000 Div's, all with absolute positioning.

The page's source code is about 1Mb, and works as expected, except for the fact that it is very sluggish on scrolling.

Is there something that can be done to get better performance? such as tell the browser to rener only what is visible or something like that?

Disclaimer: I know that a page with 5000 div's is far from optimal, but it was the only solution that allowed everbody on the network to access this table without extra software and that gave enough flexibility in creating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff below is just fighting symptoms, you really should try to re-structure your HTML. Especially there's nothing much to optimize for the browser, if it's forced to recalculate 5000 absolutely positioned elements' positions.

Also you need to test each of the following techniques, to see, if it *really* improves something with regard to your local browser array. (Chances are, that some of these tips will be counter-productive in your special set-up.)

- Work through [this HTML5Rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) and see, if anything applies to your set-up.
- [Disable pointer events on scroll](https://www.thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps), so that the browser doesn't need to check for hover states of scrolling-by elements.
- Try to [switch on hardware-accelerated rendering](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css).
- Try a [lazy image loading library](http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/), that can also be used to load arbitrary elements.
- In newer browsers, try to apply the [`will-change` CSS property](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property). Won't help you with intranet legacy browsers, though.

Comment: By the way, last week the MS Edge dev team published an article re: scrolling in browsers: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/03/08/scrolling-on-the-web/ Might be interesting for an under-the-hood view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can compute in javascript what divs are visible because your divs have absolute position.

You can try to start with all cells that are not on the first column having **display: none**, so the browser computes the height, and then set **display: block** only on those that are "visible".

As the user scrolls, use javascript to control the display attribute and so the browser computes and paints only the cells in view, and the ones that are on the first column.

It sounds complicated, and it is, but it will be fast even in older browsers.